# Why i'm getting Inconsistent accessibility: field type .... is less accessible than field ? And how to fix it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'Youtube_Manager.Ffmpeg' is less accessible than field 'Youtube_Manager.ScreenShot.fmpeg'
```

In a class top i added:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;


    namespace Youtube_Manager
    {
        public class ScreenShot
        {

        #region Global Variables
            public static Ffmpeg fmpeg;
```

Then i'm calling to use fmpeg in another class in a timer click event:

```
ScreenShot.fmpeg.Close();
```

And i'm getting in the class ScreenShot on the fmpeg the error:

Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type '`Youtube_Manager.Ffmpeg`' is less accessible than field '`Youtube_Manager.ScreenShot.fmpeg`'

And this is the top of the class Ffmpeg:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using DannyGeneral;

namespace Youtube_Manager
{
    class Ffmpeg
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream p;
        String pipename = "mytestpipe";
        System.Diagnostics.Process process;
        string ffmpegFileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
        string workingDirectory;

        public Ffmpeg()
        {
```

Even if i change the variable fmpeg from static to public i'm getting on it the same error.

Comment: Static and public have nothing to do with each other, public is access modifier, static refers to how a method is invoked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top-level C# [classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx) are internal by default.  Internal has a lower visibility than public.  Use `public class Ffmpeg` to make the class public.